# Create a Measure or Calculated Column to Find Max Date in a Column of Dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a column which is a list of variable amounts of dates. I would like to create a measure or a calculated column that will do the following:

Loop over all the individual dates to find the Latest Date.

Below is a table of what I would expect MaxDate to return.

[image]

I currently am splitting Dates in the Query Editor and finding the MAXX of the columns, but that is only a temporary solution as the number of Dates can grow quite large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in the query editor with a custom column. Use `Text.Split` to turn your `Dates` column into a list, `List.Transform` the list of text dates to date type, and then take the `List.Max`.

The formula for the custom column:

```
List.Max(List.Transform(Text.Split([Dates], ","), each Date.FromText(_)))
```